# Could the setter be omitted in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using WildFly 8.0.2 along with primefaces 5.2, i have a `p:datatable`, with a column that have a `p:inputSwitch`, the value on this `p:inputSwitch` is a method (that return either true or false), so it does not have a setter method, i have attached a `p:ajax` to handle the switching event (on/off), but when i change the value it always raise an `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation` exception (cause the value is a method ... and has no setter).
here is my code:

```
<p:column styleClass="status #{employee.haveSkill(skill) == true ? 'have' : 'dosntHave'}">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <p:inputSwitch value="#{employee.haveSkill(skill)}" onLabel="#{msgs.yes}" offLabel="#{msgs.no}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{skillsController.addSkill(employee, skill)}" />
        </p:inputSwitch>
    </div>
</p:column>
```

i have tried with a `c:set`, that stores the result of the method in a variable and then assign it to the `p:inputSwitch` component, but that didnt work for me, and the `p:inputSwitch` is always set to false (although the EL expression for the style class of the cell is working fine), here is the code that i have tried:

```
<p:column styleClass="status #{employee.haveSkill(skill) == true ? 'have' : 'dosntHave'}">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <c:set var="have" value="#{employee.haveSkill(skill)}" scope="request" />
        <p:inputSwitch value="#{have}" onLabel="#{msgs.yes}" offLabel="#{msgs.no}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{skillsController.addSkill(employee, skill)}" >
            </p:ajax>
        </p:inputSwitch>
    </div>
</p:column>
```

So is there like a way to tell jsf or el not to fire the "set" method for that component? and just execute that listener on the ajax??

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried with the `ui:param`, but it also raises the `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException` :

```
<p:column styleClass="status #{employee.haveSkill(skill) == true ? 'have' : 'dosntHave'}">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <ui:param name="have" value="#{employee.haveSkill(skill)}" />
        <p:inputSwitch value="#{have}" onLabel="#{msgs.yes}" offLabel="#{msgs.no}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{skillsController.addSkill(employee, skill)}" >
            </p:ajax>
        </p:inputSwitch>
    </div>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Implement an empty setter or use the normal way to have it set and let the actionlistener do the business work, not setting the 'skill'

Comment: what do you mean an empty setter? i have tried to create a method with this header: public `void setHaveSkill(boolean val)`, but didnt work

Comment: A setter that matches `value="#{have}"`

Comment: I gather that you found the trick in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370861/illegal-syntax-for-set-operation-how-to-tell-jsf-i-dont-want-a-setter/24416903#24416903 This will unfortunately indeed not work as intented when reused multiple times in a data table. It'll end up being the value of the last iteration round. I have a theory, but I don't have an IDE at hands right now to test it. So you should try it yourself: parameterize the key based on current iteration index/id like so `have_#{i}` and use `<c:set target/property>` and/or `#{requestScope[key]}`.